# Merge two columns which contains arrays of strings in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got PySpark dataframe which was converted into pandas df, and all values are a mess

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNJGO.png)
I want this table to look like this:

```
Line   Label       Text
47     Pain Point  text1
47     Pain Point  text2
52     Pain Point  text3
52     Competitor  text4
52     Criteria    text5
53     ...         ...
...
```

The main idea here to concatenate answer.end+question.end into Line, answer.paragraphlabels+question.paragraphlabels into Label, answer.text+question.text into Text and sort it

I have tried using `np.concatenate((df['answer.end'], df['question.end']))`, but it's giving me this result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yKjM.png) and I cannot add it to a new column. Also, I tried `df.explode(['answer.end', 'answer.paragraphlabels', 'answer.text'])` and it gave me at least data in readable format, but still is there a way to do it better?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFaPP.png)
Data provided is array of str, answer.paragraphlabels and question.paragraphlabels are nested arrays.
Please share your opinions)

Comment: Apparently it's my first time posting a question....hope it's clear what I've described(

Comment: It'll be good if you could add both input and expected output datasets in textual and tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add them together.  For example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [[1,2,99] , [2,3,4]], 
                   "b": [[5,6,7], [2,3,4]], 
                   "c": [[77,66,88], [2,3,4]],
                   'd': [['Some question', 'another question'], ['q3', 'q4']],
                   'e': [['Some answer', 'another answer'], ['a3', 'a4']],
                  })

df['a_plus_b'] = df['a'] + df['b']
df.head()
```

[image]